# Select all option values php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select all values from my MySQL database. Options a, b, and c work fine but I'm not sure of the syntax to select all three.

```
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
<option value="1,2,3">All</option>
```

Comment: Is it the HTML you're struggling with or the PHP / MySQL code?

Comment: I think he's trying to ask how to get all the items form the db. I think he uses something like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ' . $_POST['form_select_val'] . '`. in the php file. Check the value of the ALL option,

Comment: Are u trying to select `<option value="1,2,3">All</option>`

Comment: I'm struggling with the HTML bit. Maybe it can be fixed using php/mysql too though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use the select to fetch a item or all items if I understand your question correctly and by seeing your 'all' option's value.

If so then change your select option's value for all to `<option value="all">all items</option>`.

Then change your PHP file (where you posting to with the form) to this:

```
// is the all option send?
if($_POST['your_select'] === 'all') {
    //query to get all the items (SELECT * FROM table)
} else {
    // query with the post value as the id (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $_POST['your_select'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want `multiple="multiple"` it will allow you to select multiple

```
<select name="modules[]"  multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">a</option>
   <option value="2">b</option>
   <option value="3">c</option>
   <option value="1,2,3">All</option>
</select>
```

now you will get array of selected option which you can get by either `GET` or `POST`

to select all on selecting last you can use jquery like

```
$('option').click(function(){
   if($(this).val() =='1,2,3'){
    $("option").attr("selected", "selected");
   }

})
```

Comment: I think he wants to select `<option value="1,2,3">All</option>`

Comment: No luck there, unfortunately .

Comment: I want a fourth option to select all three categories.

Comment: This advice, while well-intended, extends the functionality beyond what the OP has posted.  This would allow people to select `1` and `2` without `3` OR `1` and `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="my_page.php" method="post">
    <select name="my_select">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
        <option value="1,2,3">All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php
# in my_page.php page

# put submitted value of the select tag in an array 
# (submitted value in this case equals "1", "2", "3" or "1,2,3")
$values = explode(",", $_POST["my_select"]);

# get number of values in the array
$num_of_values = count($values);

# escape all values before using them in your sql statement
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
    $values["$key"] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}

# if we have more than 1 value in the array 
if (count($values) > 1) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE "; # note the space after "WHERE" keyword

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_of_values; $i++) {
        # this "if" statement is for removing the "OR" keyword from the sql statement 
        # when we reach the last value of the array
        if ($i != $num_of_values - 1) {
            $sql .= "column_name = '{$values[$i]}' OR "; # note the space after "OR"
        } else { #if we reached the last value of the array then remove the "OR" keyword
            $sql .= "column_name = '{$values[$i]}'";
        }
    }

    # execute your query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
} else { # if we have only one value in the array
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = '{$values[0]}'");
}

?>
```