# how to create select all option from dropdown?

Tags: php, html

I am having problem in my search box, actually i have created a search box for multiple selection and it is working properly,

```
<input type="text" name="search" size=15 maxlength=15 placeholder = "Gene Symbol"/>
        <select name="table[]" size = "0" multiple>
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="infla_info">Inflammation</option>
            <option value="diet_info">diet</option>
            <option value="obesity_info">obesity</option>
            <option value="stress_info">stress</option>
            <option value="athero_info">atherosclerosis</option>
            <option value="retino_info">Diabetic Retinopathy</option>
            <option value="nephro_info">Diabetic Nephropathy</option>
            <option value="neuro_info">Diabetic Neuropathy</option>
        </select>

        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Gene Search"/>
```

after this i want to add one more option select all, by which it should show all the records or tables containing query gene.

please help me

Comment: Use javascript function for that.

Comment: @jyoti see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887619/how-to-create-select-all-option-from-dropdown/23887842#23887842)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723922/select-all-option-values-php-mysql

Answer (score 4):

try this

**Jquery Code:**

```
   $('#selectall').click(function() {
     $('#countries option').prop('selected', true);
   });
```

**Live Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/3nUPF/177/

Comment: by this do we need to select all every time? what if we need to select one or two?

Comment: for that check the working demo http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using jQuery :

**EDIT :-** You can select multiple value by pressing `Ctrl` button of your keyboard and you can get those value using `print_r($_POST['countries']);`

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" MULTIPLE size="8">
   <option value="all">Select all</option>
   <option value="UK">UK</option>
   <option value="US">US</option>
   <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
   <option value="France">France</option>
   <option value="India">India</option>
   <option value="China">China</option>
</select>
```

jQuery :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#countries').change(function() {

        if($(this).val() == 'all')
        {
            $('#countries option').prop('selected', true);
        }

    });

});

</script>
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M47T2/)**

Comment: rakesh my problem is that i have multiple tables and when i select all it should fetch matching keyword from all tables. here countries is not a list of tables i think?

Comment: how we know your tables since you have not provide anything?

Comment: in ma coding <select name="table[]" size = "0" multiple>
here this select name is table where you are providing countries which is only one table. so this is my query

Comment: any suggestion for this rakesh??

Comment: Pro Tip: There is no benefit to repeating the options' text if it is identical to the respective `value`.  Form submissions and javascipting will all still work as desired.  In other words, the option `value` declarations in the above snippet are pure markup bloat.