# Create checkbox to select all options in a selection box

Tags: php

My 2nd PHP assignment requires that I create a selection box with a range of years, a second selection box with the 12 months and then a checkbox beneath which the user can select if they want to choose an entire year. I've created the checkbox but I do not understand how to make it select all the months. I've spent over 2 hours trying to find a solution and I apologize for not having a code attempt for this particular part of my assignment. I honestly don't know where to begin.  My understanding of PHP is so narrow right now. I don't even know exactly how to properly word a google search for this problem. Every search leads me to instructions on how to create a selection box that allows for multiple selections. The only sites I've found on creating a "select all" option shows it done with JS. I must do this in PHP.

I should add that I'm only allowed to use PHP and HTML with a bit of CSS styling with this assignment.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quote.css">-->
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <form id="yearForm" name="yearForm" method="post" action="">
        <label for="select_year">Select the year: </label>
        <?php
        // Sets the default year to be the current year.
        $date = new DateTime();
//        $current_year = date('Y');
        $current_year = $date->format('Y');
        // Year to start available options.
        $earliest_year = ($current_year - 5);
        // Set your latest year you want in the range.
        $latest_year = 2050;

        echo '<select>';
        // Loops over each int[year] from current year, back to the $earliest_year [1950]
        foreach ( range( $earliest_year, $latest_year ) as $i ) {
            // Echos the option with the next year in range.
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.($i == $current_year ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>
    </form>
        <br />
        <br />
    <form id="monthForm" name="monthForm" method="post" action="">
        <label for="month">Select the month: </label>
<!--        <input type=hidden id="month" name=month>-->
                        <select id="month" name="month" >
                            <option value='01'>January</option>
                            <option value='02'>February</option>
                            <option value='03'>March</option>
                            <option value='04'>April</option>
                            <option value='05'>May</option>
                            <option value='06'>June</option>
                            <option value='07'>July</option>
                            <option value='08'>August</option>
                            <option value='09'>September</option>
                            <option value='10'>October</option>
                            <option value='11'>November</option>
                            <option value='12'>December</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <br />
        <label for="whole_year">Show whole year: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="whole_year" name="whole_year" >
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class=inline name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want the page to be reactive to the select box, doing it in PHP is going to cause you a lot of headache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723922/select-all-option-values-php-mysql

Comment: I wouldn't know an assignment with this professor that doesn't involve a lot of headache, unfortunately.  Everything must be done with php and some html.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm studying it now and trying to understand it.

Comment: The link is for adding an "all" option to the dropdown box with the other individual options.  That isn't want I'm needing to do.

Comment: You seem to know already that `selected="selected"` is used to make an option selected, and I suppose you must have already learned by now how to get the POSTed data after the form was submitted - so what are you actually still missing? If `whole_year` is in your POST data, then you have to output this attribute on every single option element in the month select field.

Comment: half of my code is trial and error. I'm learning PHP on my own.  The college offers no tutoring and my attempts to find one have been futile.  My professor's available hours total 6 hours per week and conflict with my school schedule.  And finding help online is extremely difficult because I'm limited to use only what my professor shows us in class, which seems to be what most people recommend I don't use. So, I don't really understand the code I've created but I'm hoping that eventually I will.  That's the goal.

Comment: I don't understand what "output this attribute on every single option element in the month select field" means. I don't fully understand what my POST data is. I have to display calendars that correspond with the month and year that a user chooses. If they click the "Show whole year" checkbox then, when they click Submit, a calendar for every month will display. If they leave the checkbox unchecked then only the month they chose in the selection box above it will display. I can't connect the dots ... between the "show whole year" checkbox and making sure calendars for every month display.

Comment: If you really wanted to _“Create checkbox to select all options in a selection box”_, then you need `multiple`, otherwise only one option can be selected at a time to begin with. But turns out that is not actually what you want to begin with, you don’t want to select any options inside that month field - you want to perform the action that _follows_ this selection, after the form was submitted, _as if_ all options had been selected, when the checkbox is checked. Two rather different things.

Comment: From your comments further down on the current answer, _“When the user clicks the submit button at the bottom of the page, a calendar will display for the year & month chosen”_ - then you need to show us the part where that calendar gets created, not the form that gathers the input data. _That_ is the place where you need to make the decision to output the calendar for all the month, based on that this checkbox was checked.

Comment: But using two separate forms still doesn’t make sense then. You need the info which year _and_ month to create the calendar for after submit, so this should be _one_ form sending _both_ values. (Of course this could be done in a multi-step way as well - select year first, then select month in a second step - but then you would still have to “carry over” the year selection when the month selection is submitted, so that would even further complicate things.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `multiple` attribute of select element to select multiple options as:

```
<select name="modules[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">a</option>
   <option value="2">b</option>
   <option value="3">c</option>
   <option value="1,2,3">All</option>
</select>
```

Now, you can select multiple options.

Comment: I can't allow uses to choose multiple options from the drop down box. One drop down contains a list of years. Another contains all the months. Beneath the two drop downs there must be a separate checkbox for the option to  "Show whole year". When the user clicks the submit button at the bottom of the page, a calendar will display for the year & month chosen. If they check the "Show whole year" checkbox, calendars representing all 12 months will display.  As noted in my original post, the option to choose all months has to be in a separate checkbox.